# What happens when an upcast pointer is passed by reference to a function expecting derived?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I've inherited something similar to this code:

```
class Base
{
   public:
   virtual double getElement(int i) {return NULL;}
   virtual Derived*  GetAsDerived() {return this;}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   public:
      virtual double getElement(int i) {return vec[i];}

   private:
   std::vector<double>;
};
```

And a function as follows:

```
void f(Base& b)
{
   Derived*  d = b.GetAsDerived();
}
```

The program flow is something similar to this

```
Derived A;
/*  get data into vector in A */

f(A);
```

After the call to `GetAsDerived()` in `f` .The vector in the object pointed by d contains junk.Inside the debugger I can go back in the call stack and see that the vector inside A still has valid data.

I am sure that that all this weird upcasting - downcasting is the cause but I was not able to find a formal explanation in the specs or online.

So why does it fail in such a manner?

Comment: This code won’t even compile. Please post the *real*, compiling code.

Comment: I cant post the actual code, it spans several files,  this code was to merely  annotate the problem

Comment: Yeah that makes no sense - the base class doesn't appear to have the function GetAsderived so that code wouldn't work for starters. GEtAsDerived also doesn't seem to return a pointer so that wouldn't work either.

Comment: your right, the implementation is so warped I made a mistake ,the function is actually implemented in the base class!

Comment: @Eli: Then post some code that does compile and demonstrates the problem you're seeing. This `GetAsDerived()` won't compile because it tries to return `this` which is a `Base*`, not a `Derived*`.

Comment: @Thomas: no it wont I fixed my example, the base class actually has a number of functions implementing downcast to every derived type!

Comment: Your fixed example is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Upcasting is formally defined in 4.10/3 of the standard. Downcasting is in 5.2.9/5, although that's not specifically what you're doing.

Addressing the title of your question, it's not possible to pass (or return) a base class pointer to (from) a function whose parameters (return type) indicate a derived class pointer. If the parameters indicate a reference to base class pointer, then it's not possible to pass a derived class pointer *by reference*. If a base class pointer value, it is possible to pass a derived pointer because of the implicit conversion.

I can't say why your code fails: as commented above, your real code must fail for different reasons than your example code does, since your example code doesn't work at all.

Comment: Specifically, by non-const reference...  `const` references can accept subtypes just fine.

Comment: @Ben: good point, I forgot to consider that one. The reference won't be to the derived pointer that was provided as argument, but of course the referand is still the same object (or anyway the base class subobject of the same object), so it counts.

Comment: Can't understand " If a base class pointer value".@BenVoigt@Steve Jessop

Answer (score 0):

In function `f`,`Derived*  d = b.GetAsDerived();`does not change anything about b,so it can't change the object b points to,in this case A.In `f`,If there is `b = d` or something alike,then A will be changed.